# Android app Json

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin

I writing android app and faced problem.

I have API and write it to file.

Code of writing

```
 string url2 = "http://new.murakami.ua/?mkapi=getProducts";
        JsonValue json = await FetchAsync(url2);

string path =  System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

                string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "myfile.txt");
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(json.ToString());
                    streamWriter.Close();


                }
ParseAndDisplay1(json);
        ParseAndDisplay2(json);
        ParseAndDisplay3(json);
        ParseAndDisplay4(json);
        ParseAndDisplay5(json);
        ParseAndDisplay6(json);
        ParseAndDisplay7(json);
        ParseAndDisplay8(json);

    }
 private async Task<JsonValue> FetchAsync(string url)
    {
        // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
                JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
                //dynamic data = JObject.Parse(jsonDoc[15].ToString);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());


                // Return the JSON document:
                return jsonDoc;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to read information from it and display.

I tried something like this, but it don't works.

```
        private void ParseAndDisplay1(JsonValue json)
    {



        TextView productname = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.posttittle);
        TextView price = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.price);
        TextView weight = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.weight);
        productname.Click += delegate {
            var intent404 = new Intent (this, typeof(SoupesDetailActivity1));
            StartActivity (intent404);
        };
        string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine (path, "myfile.txt");

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader (filename, true)) {
            JsonValue firstitem = json [81];

            productname.Text = firstitem ["post_title"];
            price.Text = firstitem ["price"] + " грн";
            weight.Text = firstitem ["weight"] + "г";
        }



    }
```

Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: I cannot read file and display information @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: `myfile.txt` file is already present or want to create?

Comment: already present in the root of project @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: What is the purpose of writing the json data to file and then immediately reading it again?  Why not just work with the json data you already have loaded in memory?  And why are you creating a streamreader and then never doing anything with it?

Comment: I have 10 Activities and want to load json data to file on main activity and work with it on other activities. 
StreamReader I created to load data from file, but i don't know how. @Jason

Comment: Why not just pass the data between Activities?

Comment: okay, how I can pass the data between Activities?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/

Comment: it not good for me, because I have a lot of products in my list

I want to write json to file and read from it. @Jason

Answer (score 0):

Man you are using Xamarin. But here some tips of how I solve it in Android native code.

1. I saved the file in the Assets folder;
2. them saved the fale with .json extension not .txt;
3. I accessed it using this code:

   `private static String loadJSONFromAsset(Context context, String fileName) {
           String json = null;
           try {
               InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("contactos/" + fileName + ".json");
               int size = is.available();
               byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
               is.read(buffer);
               is.close();
               json = new String(buffer);
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
               return null;
           }
           return json;
       }`
4. After that I parse the JSON with no problem.

And it works perfectly, I hope it will help you.

Comment: how i can save file with .json extension?

Comment: instead of "myfile.txt" try "myfile.json"

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many different ways to read/write data in .NET.  This is just one fairly simple approach

```
// assuming data is System.Json.JsonValue with your data

// write data to file
File.WriteAllText(path, data.ToString());

// read back data
string rawdata = File.ReadAllText(path);
// parse it into a JsonValue
JsonValue json = JsonValue.Parse(rawdata);
```